# Is there a hierarchy to functional groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I think I am getting slightly confused about the names we give to functional groups. I am aware that there are different types of functional groups such as alkyl, aryl and acyl groups.

I also know that there exist functional groups such as those of esters, ketones and amides which come under the acyl group. However, thinking about this recently I also realised that there existed a carbonyl group, which is also present in a ketone?

I am also a bit confused as to whether the acyl group's general formula is RCO or RCOX where X could be a variety of groups. Also, is R a part of the functional group or is it there to show what the functional group is attached to.

Could someone please make this hierarchy of functional groups a bit clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you may be confusing is the difference between a functional group and a moiety. A moiety is a part of the molecule that could be either the whole functional group or just a part of the structure of a functional group.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_group) does a decent job of explaining this.

[image]

In this illustration there is an ester functional group and an acetyl moeity.

As for your second question about the [acyl group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyl), my understanding is that the formula is RCO- and that the X is not necessary to define the acyl group. The R represents an alkyl group.
[image]